# customizing image src of each post in a WordPress loop

Tags: wordpress, loops

So I have a `WP_Query` looping through my custom post types and I'm looking to customize the `src` of my image tags based on which post in the loop it is. What is the cleanest way to achieve this.

consider this as what my loop is spitting out on each iteration:

```
            <div class="partnerships p-section">
                <div class="-display-inlineBlock partnerships icon">
                  <img style="min-width:71px;" src="<?php bloginfo('template_url')?>/images/icons/trainingAndDevelopment.svg">
                </div>
                <div class="-display-inlineBlock" style="width:70%">
                    <h1><?php the_title();?></h1>
                    <hr>
                   <p><?php the_content(); ?>
                   </p>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why you don't use post thumbnail?

```
<div class="partnerships p-section">
    <div class="-display-inlineBlock partnerships icon">
      <img style="min-width:71px;" src="<?php the_post_thumbnail_url(); ?>">
    </div>
    <div class="-display-inlineBlock" style="width:70%">
        <h1><?php the_title();?></h1>
        <hr>
       <p><?php the_content(); ?>
       </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

EDIT:

Then you need to allow upload SVG.

But BE WARNING: Allow upload SVG is not good for security
(take a look: https://secupress.me/blog/add-svg-support-in-wordpress-medias-yes-but-no/)

So DO NOT USE THE FOLLOWING CODE, which one can see everywhere.

```
function custom_mtypes( $m ){
    $m['svg'] = 'image/svg+xml';
    $m['svgz'] = 'image/svg+xml';
    return $m;
}
add_filter( 'upload_mimes', 'custom_mtypes' )
```

## FIRST SOLUTION

I don't know how to clean SVG on upload, luckily a plugin that does all that exists. This plugin also fixes some others issues with svg.

https://wordpress.org/plugins/scalable-vector-graphics-svg/

## SECOND SOLUTION

### If only admin need to upload svg

You can use following code:

```
function custom_mtypes( $m ){
    if(get_current_user_id()==1){
        $m['svg'] = 'image/svg+xml';
        $m['svgz'] = 'image/svg+xml';
        return $m;
    }
}

add_filter( 'upload_mimes', 'custom_mtypes' );
```

If you speak French here is an interesting discussion on this subject
https://wpchannel.com/autoriser-envoi-fichiers-svg-wordpress/  (read comments, DON'T USE THE CODE on the top of this article)